# How to force drop an operator in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

My database has implicit cast from integer to text, so I'm getting some 'operator is not unique' issues. I'm trying to delete the operator || (text, anynonarray) with no success, the error message is

> ERROR: cannot drop operator ||(text,anynonarray) because it is required by the database system
>   SQL state: 2BP01

I have another database that doesn't have this operator, so I think is possible somehow. I cannot add explicit casts in hundreds of queries, neither remove the implicit casts. There's a way to force the remotion of this operator?

Comment: 2BP01 means it has dependent objects, Did you try it with cascade in your drop command? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-dropoperator.html Be careful with cascades it might drop more then you want so make a backup first.

Comment: DROP OPERATOR ||(anynonarray, text) CASCADE; the error continues.

Comment: It's a system operator i.e. you can't drop it.

Comment: But there's another database here and it doesn't have these operators!

Comment: What are the PostgreSQL versions involved?

Comment: select version(); "PostgreSQL 8.4.6 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10), 64-bit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I got it. The trick is to delete right from the pg_operator table.

```
delete from pg_operator where oprname = '||' and (oprleft = 25 or oprleft = 2776 ) and oprleft != oprright
```

Because I wanted to delete these operators:

> OPERATOR ||("text", anynonarray);
>
> OPERATOR ||(anynonarray, "text");

I don't know if there are any implications though, seems ok till now.

Comment: You are deleting operators from the basic Postgres system: `textanycat` and `anytextcat`. Expressions of the form `'a'::text || '1'::int` or `'1'::int || 'a'::text` that would normally evaluate to the text `a1` / `1a` will produce an error. An extension or client or any SQL code may be assuming these operators and fail unexpectedly. In short: **Don't try this at home!**

Comment: select 'a'::text || '1'::int and the other didn't produce error though